# Why isn't my increment working correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, increment

I have a simple system in which photos have many comments.
I'm sure I'm not doing this right, but I am trying to build a simple rating system for the comments. `comment.rating` starts at 0 and can go up.

This is a portion of my Comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def increment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.rating += 1
    redirect_to(@photo)
  end

end
```

I think the `increment` method is fine, but how I'm calling it is not:

```
<%= link_to "+", :controller => 'comments', :method => 'increment' %>
```

That doesn't work. I realize this is a bit of a fundamental question, but I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointers everyone. I thought I was a lot further off than I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are not passing a comment :id to params.

You could do so by defining a route like this in your `routes.rb` file:

```
match 'increment_rating/:comment_id' => 'Comments#increment', :as => 'increment_rating'
```

with your `increment` action now beginning with

```
def increment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
    ...
end
```

and then call it from the view with

```
<%= link_to '+', increment_rating_path(comment.id) %>
```

where `comment.id` gives the id of the comment whose rating you want to increment

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to "+" , :controller => "comments", :action => "increment", :id => @comment %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to "+" , :controller => "comments", :action => "increment", :id => comment.id %>
```

Keep in mind usually such action would use POST or PUT, in which case you need to specify :method with either :post or :put.

If you have added the increment in routes, you could also use:

```
<%= link_to "+", increment_comment_path(comment.id) %>
```